# By 2030, new well-paid jobs "will be"/"will have been" available

Tags: tense, future-tense

Here is the question:

> By 2030, new well-paid jobs (will be - will have been - had been - were being) available in London.

This was a question in my exam. I chose "will have been", but my instructor told me that both answers are correct ("will be", "will have been"), so I'm confused now. Which one is really the most correct? Please include an explanation

Comment: Though both are correct, I think the 'will have been' (future perfect) is least practiced. However, I'd write: *"... jobs will have been made available..."*

Comment: @MaulikV  It's actually a future state. "Well-paid jobs are available" refers not to an action but to a state. Compare : "The sky is clear." That refers to a state. So does "By 5 p.m the sky will be clear." We can refer to states in the past, present, and future.